# Find best layout to reduce use of space or material

Tags: algorithms

#### Example case:

You have a truck, that can hold 2.8m by 3.2m by 16m of storage capacity.
You you get a bunch of physical objects you want to store in that truck.
These objects are not always cubic, but sometimes rounded, or have concave shapes.

#### The problem to solve

I want to implement an algorithm, that finds the optimal way to put 3D objects of any shape into 3D space, without intersecting and using up the least amount of space (volume) and possibly other criteria(high fragility not to be put under high mass for example).
I'm not specifically asking on how to do it(although that would be great), but at least know how the process of working out the optimal layout is called, so I can do further research myself.

The closest thing I've found was related to using least amount of leather for making shoes. There was a presentation that referenced a software doing that, but it's no longer available. Also adding a 3rd dimension to this doesn't seem trivial to me.

I think I'm either searching for the wrong keywords on this, or there hasn't been done a lot of research on these kinds of problems(which seems unlikely to me, since I've heard of a friend it's a subject of engineering)

#### Final questions

1. How do you call the process of finding the optimal layout?
2. Is there a generic approach to this type of problem(and what is it)?

Comment: another example of such a problem would be encountered putting objects into boxes for delivery.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: @RobertHarvey wow, i have no idea why i didn't went into that article during my search. thank you very much! I think I should've tried searching for the exact problem instead of straight solution -.-

Answer (score 0):

Threre is a herustic  I use for packing  grocery bags. Basically the key is well ordering prinicipal.

First use the space on the back and sides first . Basically max distance from loading cross sectional area. That is for practicality of not stuffing objects in the very back after most the space is used. The most big objects go there.

Then, put most durable objects on the floor. If two objects are equally durable, put the big one first.

Next, put the smallest but non fragile objects in any remaining space. These should be asked to fit in knooks and cranies.

Lastly, place the fragile objects in but only on the very top of other objects. Highly elastic objects that change shape easily would also go here.

If you constantly have more objects than space allows, then try running the above herustic in a loop trying to add one more object and have it fit. For that, have list start prioritized by ship dates. For ties, put most money given to company as first.

Comment: Thanks you for sharing your heuristic with me. Although your 'algorithm' seems quite good, also implementing multiple critera weight, size and fragility, it doesn't really add much to my previous research of the bin packing problem.
My current problem is, that I don't know the exact circumstances and likelyhoods of the objtects shapes. I was hoping for a perfect solution, one, that is proven to be the best. Unfortunately, nobody has done this before, other than bruteforcing at some defined resolution. There might always be a better solution, when increasing resolution by just a tiny bit.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Robert Harvey before, these sorts of problems are - most of the times - referred to as [`packing problems`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems)

There are a lot of examples, where you are dealing with regular shapes(shapes, that are all the same). Your case is not one of them. Your case categorizes to having irregular shapes, and also in 3-dimensional space.

#### One idea

How about that:

1. Take the biggest object (by the means of longest distance between two points of the object)
2. Place it on top of the 'bin'
3. Perform physical simulation(collision, gravity), shaking the 'bin' around
4. Repeat, until you are out of space placing the next object